# How do I propose a transaction on Gnosis Safe from a non-owner?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'd like to construct and propose a transaction for a Gnosis Safe multisig via the Gnosis API. I want these transactions to show up in the Gnosis frontend, so signers can sign & submit the transactions.

I *do not* want to submit a signature from one of the signers on the Safe at the time of proposing the transaction. This is because each of the keys are hardware wallets held by disparate signers, and I don't want to export any of those keys and expose them.

In the [API documentation for proposing transactions](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/tutorials/tutorial_tx_service_initiate_sign#proposing-transactions), it says that "Transactions submitted as a non-owner will not show up on the official Safe interfaces unless you previously added a delegate." However, the [link for the tutorial](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-docs/tree/98cffd3359a173173543997a027134572e00cf29/tutorials/tutorial_tx_service_set_delegate.md) for adding a delegate is broken.

How can I add a delegate which can propose transactions via the API (but which is not an owner of the Safe)?

Answer (score 0):

The link is indeed broken. Here a reference to the old docs:

- https://github.com/gnosis/safe-docs/blob/devportal/docs/tutorial_tx_service_set_delegate.md

An example application where a delegate key is registered can be found here:

- https://github.com/rmeissner/sapp-admin-tools/blob/master/src/utils/repositories/delegateRepository.ts#L33-L40

You can also find the endpoints on the services swagger page:

- https://safe-transaction.gnosis.io/ (search for `delegate`)

Maybe also helpful is the tutorial on how to propose a transaction (where you would use the delegate key then):

- https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/tutorials/tutorial_tx_service_initiate_sign